# What could cause a drawer in a bedside table to become stuck?

Tags: bedroom

Firstly, I apologise if this has been posted in the wrong place but I thought it would be worth starting here!

I have a bedside table with three drawers - I'm in no way whatsoever a DIY person, so all I understand about these is that they're all connected to individual runners. Whilst two of the drawers worked without issue and would open all of the way up, my top drawer wouldn't and would only open about half way. Thinking that something might have been blocking it from opening completely, I reached my hand inside and to the back of the unit - but nothing existed in the gap that could be the cause. Then, with one hand I slowly began to pull the drawer from the very back - this worked, and the drawer eventually came all the way out. I haven't had any problems with it since.

Now - my question. If there was nothing that could have been physically causing the drawer not to open, what could this have been? As mentioned, since using some force to open the drawer it has been absolutely fine since.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What sort of runners? Old-school wooden ones (and their slots) can wear, which can lead to intermittent misalignment. Metal ones can bend out of shape.

Comment: May just need  to be cleaned and dirt, causing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the drawers have the more modern full extension ball bearing slides it is possible for the slider intermediate rail to get aligned to one end opposite it's normal operating position. This can cause the drawer to either not pull out all the way or not close all the way when you push/pull the drawer with gentle force. A higher force will cause the intermediate rail to slide on its balls instead of rolling thus getting the piece into it's proper position.

Comment: This makes sense - just what I was looking for. Thank you. :)